# How do I stop Xcode from looking for OS X Products in iphoneos build directories?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, configuration, product

I have a project that started out as an iOS project, and it properly finds Products in `build/Debug-iphoneos` and `build/Release-iphoneos`. I have since added some OS X targets, and they are properly built in the `build/Debug` and `build/Release` directories.

However, when I click on an OS X Product in the Products section of the Navigator area, Xcode is looking for it in `build/Release-iphoneos`, not `build/Release`. When I look at the target, the build products path is properly set to `build/Release`. What's going on? Why does Xcode think the product will be in `build/Release-iphoneos` but properly builds it in `build/Release`? How can I get it to find it in the proper place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much faffing about, I've come to the conclusion that this is simply not currently possible. The issue seems to be that, although Targets build products in the appropriate platform-specific directories, Xcode only knows about and looks for products in the project-default build products path (CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR). Since Xcode has no problem letting me create and build targets for OS X and iOS in a single project, I believe that this is a shortcoming with its handling of Products, so I filed a [bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5342783153897472) (rdar://19163498).